# Rewrite rules in the .htaccess file

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The request is simple, however, I cannot find a way to implement it. I have links like:

```
httр://mysite.com/index.php?lang=EN
httр://mysite.com/index.php?route=add&lang=EN
httр://mysite.com/index.php?route=view&lang=EN
```

and so on. What I want is to create 301 redirects so that EN could be changed to GB. For example, if a customer opens `httр://mysite.com/index.php?route=add&lang=EN`, he should be redirected to `httр://mysite.com/index.php?route=add&lang=GB`.

I have searched for this for days and have failed to find a working solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done in .htaccess? Here's a relatively simple way of doing it in PHP:

```
<?
if ("EN" == $_GET['lang']) {
  $params = $_GET;
  $params['lang'] = "GB";
  $query_strings = array();
  foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $query_strings[] = $key . "=" . $value;
  }
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
  header("Location: http://www.mysite.com?" . join($query_strings, "&");
}
```

Bottom line is that it may be easier to fix this problem on a level where you can isolate each query parameter and look at just the `lang` parameter and determine whether to do a redirect.

With regular expressions (as you would need to use in .htaccess) it's harder to isolate just the `lang` part. You would also need one line per language you want to redirect and maintain the list.

Comment: Hello fiskeben, thank you very much for this. Yes, it is preferable for me to have this to be done via .htaccess. However, if I do not find a way, I'll use your solution.